# como crear un json web token desde angular?

Tags: angular, jwt, jsonwebtoken

Mi duda es, puedo crear un `jwt` desde angular, existe alguna libreria en angular que me permita hacer esto, de momento estoy usando para la libreria `@auth0/angular-jwt` y segun lo que investige en [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt), las unicas funciones que existen son:

```
const decodedToken = helper.decodeToken(myRawToken);
const expirationDate = helper.getTokenExpirationDate(myRawToken);
const isExpired = helper.isTokenExpired(myRawToken);
```

no encuentro una que sea similar a `jwt.sign(...)` de `jsonwebtoken`. Asi que quiero saber si existe una libreria que me permita hacer esto, y si la unica es `jsonwebtoken`, como la puedo implementar en angular?

Comment: ¿No se supone que los JWT se generan en un servidor? ¿Por qué querrías hacer esto en el lado del cliente?

Comment: para mandar datos sensibles que no quiero que se vean del cliente al servidor, por ejemplo el correo y la contraseña al momento de hacer un login

Comment: Para eso se envían los datos con `https` y asunto arreglado.

Comment: @TDPerez ¿No desea enviar datos de inicio de sesión al servidor? ¿Cómo puede autenticarse en ese esquema?

Answer (score 0):

Si un usuario escribe una contraseña en tu aplicación, no tiene sentido ocultárselo, si quieres que esa información se oculte a los usuarios de la misma red, eso se hace automáticamente en producción con los certificados SSL (lo más probable es que lidiará con esto en la implementación, SSL encripta todos los datos entre el usuario y el servidor).

Básicamente, no obtiene casi nada al hacer ese enfoque, en su lugar, debe crear el lado del servidor jwt donde sus claves secretas estén seguras.

Answer (score 0):

Es innecesario generar un token en el front, cualquiera con conocimientos minimos podra decifrarlo y usar la informacion, aun asi responderé con el procedimiento para poder generar un token firmado usando solo la libreria Crypto-js.

Lo primero es instalar las dependencias:

```
npm i --save crypto-js @types/crypto-js
```

Lo siguiente será crear un metodo que convierta nuestra informacion a un base64:

```
  base64url(source: any) {
    let encodedSource = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(source);

    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/=+$/, '');

    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/\+/g, '-');
    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/\//g, '_');

    return encodedSource;
  }
```

Despues tendremos que crear es el metodo para generar el token sin firmar:

```
  encodeToken(payload:any) {
    var header = {
      "alg": "HS256",
      "typ": "JWT"
    };

    var stringifiedHeader = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(header));
    var encodedHeader = this.base64url(stringifiedHeader);

    var stringifiedData = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(payload));
    var encodedData = this.base64url(stringifiedData);

    var token = encodedHeader + "." + encodedData;
  }
```

y por ultimo un metodo que firme el token con nuestra clave secreta:

```
  signToken(payload:any,key:string) {
    var secret = key;
    let token:any = this.encodeToken(payload);

    var signature:any = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(token, secret);
    signature = this.base64url(signature);

    var signedToken = token + "." + signature;
    return signedToken;
  }
```

Ya para poder llamarlo solo consumes signToken() enviando como primer argumento el objeto a esconder y el segundo es la clave para firmar el token.

Comment: ¿No debería el método `encodeToken` devolver el token?